# Using ReportLab inside Flask server crashes

Tags: python, flask, reportlab

I have a Flask app that does the following:
([here's the source code](https://github.com/sebastian-meckovski/web-invoicer/blob/main/app.py))

- takes input from the user
- creates variables based on user input
- passes variables to the `exportPDF()` function
- The `exportPDF()` function enerates a PDF file based on user input
- Redirects user to download URL so the user receives that PDF file in the browser

It already works but only once. If I want to reuse the page it crashes. Here's the error:

```
[2021-03-05 15:21:53,306] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\sebas\desktop\web-invoicer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "c:\users\sebas\desktop\web-invoicer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in 
full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "c:\users\sebas\desktop\web-invoicer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in 
handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "c:\users\sebas\desktop\web-invoicer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in 
reraise
raise value
File "c:\users\sebas\desktop\web-invoicer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in 
full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "c:\users\sebas\desktop\web-invoicer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in 
dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\sebas\Desktop\web-invoicer\app.py", line 49, in home
export_PDF(sample_list, full_name=full_name, adress_line=adress_line)
File "C:\Users\sebas\Desktop\web-invoicer\invoicingCopy2.py", line 141, in export_PDF
document.save()
File "c:\users\sebas\desktop\web-invoicer\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfgen\canvas.py", line 
1277, in save
self._doc.SaveToFile(self._filename, self)
File "c:\users\sebas\desktop\web-invoicer\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 
207, in SaveToFile
raise RuntimeError("class %s instances can only be saved once" % self.__class__.__name__)
RuntimeError: class PDFDocument instances can only be saved once
```

I'm running out of ideas about what could be the issue. Ple

Comment: Hey Sebastian, I just cloned your repo and I cannot reproduce your problem. I can both create PDFs by just clicking the export button several times, and also by reloading the page and entering new infos. Is ist meanwhile fixed?

Comment: Btw - I like the layout of the PDF, looks good!

Comment: Lol, I guess I am one hour late :-) https://github.com/sebastian-meckovski/web-invoicer/commit/7faf0b2c5db0b46e442c082b7640664d173c02a1

Comment: Hello J.G! Thank you for your response!  Sorry I'm only seeing your message now. Yes, I did find out what the issue was! It was a silly mistake - one of the ReportLab lines was not in the exportPDF function. I'll post it in an answer section